# How can I aggregate counts of specific values in an array (SQL)?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have one field that can hold up to 15 different values in an array.  There are about 90 different values that can be stored for those values.

The eventual output I am looking to get is one row for each value with a column for the name of the value and the count of that value within that array.

Here is a crude example:

| **Color Combination (array)** |

| [Red],[Blue],[Yellow]     |

| [Blue],[Green],[Purple]   |

| [Yellow],[Blue]                 |

So my goal is to eventually get to an output like this:

| **Color** | **# of Times Found** |

| Yellow    | 2                    |

| Blue      | 2                    |

| Red       | 1                    |

| Green     | 1                    |

| Purple    | 1                    |

Any insights would be super helpful (not very familiar with arrays in SQL), I started with making a case statement to see if it contains the variable and then made columns for each variable with 1s if it is found, but this doesn't do me much good when I need to order the # of times found since I end up with 90 columns and 1 row with the total number of times that is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) to expand the array column:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (colors) AS (
    VALUES (array [ 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow' ]),
        (array [ 'Yellow', 'Orange' ]),
        (array [ 'Green' ])
)

--query
select color, count(*) times
from dataset
cross join unnest (colors) t(color)
group by color
order by 2 desc -- to prettify output
```

Output:

| color | times |
| --- | --- |
| Yellow | 2 |
| Red | 1 |
| Blue | 1 |
| Orange | 1 |
| Green | 1 |